# Q_OBJECT generates many errors

Tags: c++, qt, qobject

This class no problem:

```
#include <QThread>

class LiveImageItem : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    LiveImageItem(QPixmap pimg);

signals:

public slots:

};
```

---

BUT this class get problem associated with "Q_OBJECT" macro defined in header file

```
#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>

class LiveImageItem : public QGraphicsPixmapItem
{

    Q_OBJECT //this line will generate many errors in compiling

public:
    LiveImageItem(QPixmap pimg);

signals:

public slots:

};
```

both their cpp file is the same:

```
#include "LiveImageItem.h"

LiveImageItem::LiveImageItem(QPixmap pimg)
{
}
```

I thought every QT object essentially inherited from QObject so if I inherit any of the subclass of QObject, I could have all the magics QObject offers. The 2nd version of the above (which is inherited from, say, QGraphicsPixmapItem) seems proved I was wrong. It turns out to be having lots of errors while compiling, all from moc files(automatically generated by QT). What happens?

Some of these errors are:

- [qobject.h] error: 'QScopedPointer QObject::d_ptr' is
  protected
- [moc_LiveImageItem.cpp] error: within this context
- ...

Comment: I see that you're inheriting from QThread for LiveImageItem...you should read this: http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation `QGraphicsPixmapItem` is not a `QObject`, thus you cannot treat it as if it is. I would try to extend your class inheritance and do:

```
class LiveImageItem : public QObject, public QGraphicsPixmapItem
{

    Q_OBJECT //this line will generate many errors in compiling
[..]
```

Comment: QObject or QGraphicsObject

Answer (score 1):

As @vahancho said, QGraphicsPixmapItem is not a QObject. In fact, that can be said of most of the QGraphics*Item classes.

However, if you want to use signals and slots with QGraphicsSystem classes, you can inherit from [QGraphicsObject](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsobject.html): -

```
class LiveImageItem : public QGraphicsObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:


    private:
        QPixmap m_pixmap;
};
```

You would then override the paint function in this class and draw the pixmap from there.